# Python discord.py delete a chat with with a certain id/message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am setting up a games bot for discord and the first game I am making is rock, paper, scissors as I am new to discord.py and this seems a good, simple way to start making discord games.

The trouble im having is obviously the users could enter their answers at different times so I want the bot to delete the answer the user gives as soon as it sent.

I would use `ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)` but I dont know if this is suitable for busy servers where a message could be sent straight after and the users response would not be the one to be deleted.

When I right click on a chat, I can see the option `copy id` and was wondering if the bot can access this and also delete chats using a certain id.

Also, it would probably be better if the user could send their response through PM's and be able to process the data that way so if anyone could explain how to do that that would be even better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get specific replies by using [`wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for).

## Example:

```py
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Hey {ctx.author.mention}! Send a message for me to delete!")
    
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author # you can also check m.content for specific keywords
        # if the check returns true, the message is plopped into the reply variable \/
    try:
        reply = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=30)
                # times out after 30 seconds if no response matching the check is received
                # reply is just a message object, meaning you can get .content, .id etc.
                # this means you can also perform functions if the bot has the permissions

        await reply.delete() # this won't be necessary if you're using the bot in DMs
        await ctx.send("Message deleted!")

    except asyncio.TimeoutError: # this is the error thrown when it times out
        await ctx.send("You didn't reply in time :(")
```

As it said in the code above, you can also get the content of the reply, so in your case you would be able to check `reply.content.lower()` if it is equal to `rock`, `paper` etc.

The documentation also shows the case for waiting for reactions, so you could get the game to work with the user reacting to the message with R/P/S emojis.

## Deleting a message from a given ID

```py
# using a specific command
@bot.command(name="deletemsg") # deletemsg will be what you type in as the cmd on discord
async def delete_specific_message(ctx, msg: discord.Message):
    await msg.delete()

# getting message object
@bot.command()
async def mycmd(ctx):
    # some stuff
    msg = await ctx.fetch_message(ID_GOES_HERE) # you will need a channel object to fetch
                                                # the message from
```

Comment: ahah i was gonna dm you but i was like ive already bothered you enough today and yet here you are! YOU ARE DA BEST!

Comment: Haha, I'm just lurking here throughout the day, you'll see me every now and again :)

Comment: @LegacyCoding Also edited the answer to tackle another way to delete messages from an ID